# What is the difference between perspective and transform's perspective properties in CSS?

Tags: css

In our application we use a temporary css transform as a page transition.

With the latest build of google chrome (37) this stopped working. The transformation has no longer a perspective.

Fiddling with the developer tools I was able to restore the correct behavior by changing the definition of the perspective on the parent element from

```
perspective: 2000px;
```

to

```
transform: perspective(2000px);
```

My question is: is something wrong with our existing declaration (using the perspectice property) or is this a bug in google chrome?

I tried to recreate the problem below, but in the reduced example I see the reverse effect, that now perspective works and transform:perspective not.

Any thoughts?

```css
.perspective-Parent {
    /*-moz-transform: perspective(2000px);
    -ms-transform: perspective(2000px);
    -o-transform: perspective(2000px);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(2000px);
    transform: perspective(2000px);*/
  
    -moz-perspective: 2000px;
    -ms-perspective: 2000px;
    -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
    perspective: 2000px; 
  
    -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%; 
 }

.page {
   background-color: red;
    
   -moz-transform-origin: right center;
   -ms-transform-origin: right center;
   -o-transform-origin: right center;
 -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
   transform-origin: right center;
   
   -ms-transform: rotateY(75deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateY(75deg);
   -o-transform: rotateY(75deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(75deg);
    transform: rotateY(75deg);
  
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p>
<div class="perspective-Parent">
  <div class="page">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [This CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/) has your answer :)

Comment: @Harry Thanks for the link. Very interesting. But as far as I see, since I have only one child, there should be no difference?

Comment: I have the same question mate and thats why I had not posted it as an answer. I thought atleast you would be able to catch something that I couldn't by going through the link. I couldn't cross check either because I am using a lower version of Chrome in which the code in question still works.

Comment: @Harry I see. So let's wait if someone clears this up :-)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "perspective works and transform:perspective not", is there no perspective/effect being applied or is it just not the one you expect?

Comment: @apaul34208 There is no perspective at all.

Comment: If you're putting `transform: perspective()` on the parent and `transform: rotate()` on the child it may be the cause of the problem. You would need `transform: perspective() rotate()` on the child or the parent. Or `perspective: ;` on the parent and `transform: rotate()` on the child. Does that make sense?

Comment: @apaul34208 Hmm, not sure. It works in IE, Safari und Firefox. It worked (!) in chrome < 37. I'm beginning to think it's a bug in chrome. But I can't create a simple repro :-(

Comment: @apaul34208 try: demo.arcplan.com, a click on one of the tile navigates to another page (with a transition). Try it in different browsers..

Comment: OK it looks like if you change `transform: rotateY(25deg);` to `transform: perspective(2000px) rotateY(25deg);` on all of your `pageContainer-...` elements, like `pageContainer-search` and so on, you'll get a consistent effect. Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My basic understanding of perspective vs transform perspective is simply that the plain perspective attribute is what you usually use on a parent element to give multiple children the same perspective, while transform perspective would be used on a child element or an individual element to give it its own perspective.

This is most easily seen when you are applying these effects to more than one element:

`perspective: ;` on a parent element:

```css
.perspective-Parent {
  -moz-perspective: 2000px;
  -ms-perspective: 2000px;
  -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
  perspective: 2000px;
  -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.page {
  background-color: red;
  -moz-transform-origin: right center;
  -ms-transform-origin: right center;
  -o-transform-origin: right center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  transform-origin: right center;
  -ms-transform: rotateY(75deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(75deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(75deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(75deg);
  transform: rotateY(75deg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px; /* added to make difference more visible */ 
}
```

```html
<div class="perspective-Parent">
  <div class="page"></div>
  <div class="page"></div>
  <div class="page"></div>
</div>
```

Notice that all three "pages" in the above example are being viewed from a common perspective.

---

`transform: perspective();` on the individual elements:

```css
.page {
  background-color: red;
  -moz-transform-origin: right center;
  -ms-transform-origin: right center;
  -o-transform-origin: right center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  transform-origin: right center;
  -ms-transform: perspective(2000px) rotateY(75deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(2000px) rotateY(75deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(2000px) rotateY(75deg);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(2000px) rotateY(75deg);
  transform: perspective(2000px) rotateY(75deg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px; /* added to make difference more visible */ 
}
```

```html
<div class="perspective-Parent">
  <div class="page"></div>
  <div class="page"></div>
  <div class="page"></div>
</div>
```

Notice on this example that the three "pages" each have their own perspective.

---

Now that that's all out of the way...

Neither approach is incorrect they just offer different visual effects, just pick the one that you prefer.

Comment: For the second example, in Chrome 38.0.2125.111 m, all three pages have the same perspective.

Comment: @apaul In your 2nd example, using perspective: 2000px would also yield same effects?

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer here is not correct.

You can indeed do a perspective transform on a parent element. For this to work, you need to set transform-style: preserve-3d; on the parent.

```css
.perspective-Parent{
  transform: perspective(2000px);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.page {
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transform: rotateY(75deg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="perspective-Parent">
<div class="page">
</div>
<div class="page">
</div><div class="page">
</div>
</div>
```

When I test out different perspectives in chrome, the perspective property gives some strange distortions.

```css
.box{
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.no-perspective-box{ 
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(15deg);
}

.perspective-prop-box{
  perspective: 7.5cm;
  transform-style: preserve-3d; /*This is required here too*/
  transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(15deg);
}

.perspective-box{ 
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: perspective(7.5cm) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(15deg);
}

.face{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.top{
  background-color: blue;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
}

.left{
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
}

.front{
  background-color: green;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
}
```

```html
<p>Without Perspective:</p>
<div class="box no-perspective-box">
  <div class="face front">A</div>
  <div class="face top">B</div>
  <div class="face left">C</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<p>With Perspective Property:</p>
<div class="box perspective-prop-box">
  <div class="face front">A</div>
  <div class="face top">B</div>
  <div class="face left">C</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<p>With Perspective Function:</p>
<div class="box perspective-box">
  <div class="face front">A</div>
  <div class="face top">B</div>
  <div class="face left">C</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

The order matters in case of declaring the property and the function, the "perspective" function must come right after the "transform" property!

WRONG CODE

```
transform:rotateX(45deg) perspective(100px);
```

CORRECT CODE

```
transform:perspective(100px) rotate(45deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

To activate 3D space, an element needs perspective. This can be applied in two ways: using the transform property, with the perspective as a functional notation.

```
transform: perspective( 600px );
```

or using the perspective property:

```
perspective: 600px;
```

> **[Perspective Projection vs. Perspective Transformation](http://cs.brown.edu/stc/summer/2ViewRender/2ViewRender_11.html)**
>
> **Perspective Projection** calculates the perspective view (i.e., foreshortening) of a 3D object onto a 2D projection plane. The effect
>   of viewing in perspective is achieved, and, of course, the z-values
>   (depth information) are discarded in the process.
>
> **Perspective Transformation** allows us to see how the perspectively foreshortened and projected polygons will overlap, without discarding
>   the z-values (which we need to use later for depth comparison).

Comment: Seems you are quoting from [this source](http://cs.brown.edu/stc/summer/2ViewRender/2ViewRender_11.html), therefore you must cite the source.

Comment: @HashemQolami thanks for the edit, will surely add it here onwards