# Is there any difference between CSS perspective rule and value?

Tags: css, css-transforms

Is there any difference between these two?

```
perspective: 600px;
transform: perspective(600px);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this website](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/perspective.html) there is.

> These two formats both trigger a 3D space, but there is a difference. The functional notation is convenient for directly applying a 3D transform on a single element ... But when used on multiple elements, the transformed elements don’t line up as expected. If you use the same transform across elements with different positions, each element will have its own vanishing point. To remedy this, use the perspective property on a parent element, so each child may share the same 3D space.

Answer (score 0):

> ...the perspective property doesn't affect how the element is rendered; it simply enables a 3D-space for children elements. This is the main difference between the transform: perspective() function and the perspective property. The first gives element depth while the later creates a 3D-space shared by all its transformed children.

The full article can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/

And a similar question here: [What is the difference between perspective and transform's perspective properties in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910933/what-is-the-difference-between-perspective-and-transforms-perspective-propertie)

So the main difference seems to be whether or not you would like the perspective to be applied to all children in the same way (`transform: perspective` would be applied to the parent), or if you want a child element to have its own perspective.