# CSS3 3D flip card effect with SVG elements

Tags: css, svg, d3.js

Is there a way to create CSS3 3D flip card-like effect in SVG created with d3.js?

I need to have part of a D3 chart flip over, revealing different content on the back, similar to the effect described in [this tutorial by David DeSandro](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html) for HTML elements.

The [animate.css library](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) includes effects like these.  Is there a way to apply it to parts of a D3 chart?

Comment: Yes of course, you can apply CSS to SVG or to the container element of the SVG (which could have that transform).

Comment: Not really, 
$('svg #myChartId').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft') doesn't work while $('#someDiv').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft') works !

Comment: Not everything that works for HTML will work for SVG as well. But as I've said, you can always put your chart in an HTML container element and apply the styles to that.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I actually need to create a flip effect inside a section of d3 generated chart.

Comment: Well you can use transitions on the transform for this. The idea is to apply the transform that makes it flip and then simply add a transition.

Comment: Haven't worked with D3 charts so don't know much. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104850/flipping-card-issue/25105063#25105063) answer has a general implementation of the card flip effect using `transforms` and `transitions` (like mentioned in the above comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you're using d3.js does not at all affect the ability to create 3D transforms.  The fact that you are using SVG, however, does make it complicated.

SVG has its own transform system—and coordinate system—that doesn't directly correspond to the way that CSS transforms are applied to HTML elements.  Although [the CSS transforms spec is supposed to apply to SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/), browser implementations are still very inconsistent.

As Lars said in the comments, if you wanted to flip your entire SVG, it would be simply a matter of applying the CSS transformations (as described [in the answer linked by @Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104850/flipping-card-issue/25105063#25105063)) to a parent `<div>`.  However, in order to get an individual SVG element or group to "flip" to reveal different content, you need two different SVG elements, which super-impose one on top of the other when one of them is flipped using CSS transforms.

You *can* apply CSS transformations to individual SVG elements, but beware:

- IE will ignore them completely
- Firefox (v32 and earlier) and Chrome (v37 and earlier) will calculate the transform-origin differently, so you'll want to position your elements such that the SVG coordinate system origin (used by Chrome) is the same as the bounding box origin (used by Firefox).
- Chrome won't flip individual text elements.
- SVG doesn't currently have a z-index, so you can't use it to make sure the correct element is "on top".  Instead, you would have to hide the flipped element using the [`backface-visibility` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#backface-visibility-property).

The below example is extracted [from a longer discussion about CSS transforms and SVG that I wrote on CodePen](http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/aDhrs?editors=110).  Test it in a couple different browsers to get an idea of the problems you're up against:

```css
svg.graphic {
  padding:2em 1.2%;
  margin:0;
  float:left;
  overflow:visible;
  shape-rendering:geometricPrecision;
  stroke-width:3;
}
.graphic.CSS {
  -webkit-perspective:500px;
  perspective:500px;
}
.graphic.CSS.spin *{
  -webkit-transition:3s linear;
  transition:3s linear;
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
  transform-origin:50% 50%;
}
.graphic.CSS.spin:hover *{
  -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
  transform:rotateY(360deg);
}
```

```html
<svg class="graphic CSS spin">
  <g id="svg-shapes">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" rx="2em" 
          fill="lightblue" stroke="green" />
    <circle r="1.5em" cy="2.5em" cx="70%" 
            fill="lightyellow" stroke="goldenrod" />
    <rect width="5em" height="2em" x="20%" y="2.5em" 
          fill="lavender" stroke="indigo" />
  </g>
  <text x="20%" dx="2.5em" text-anchor="middle" 
        y="2.5em" dy="1em">3D???</text>
</svg>
```

If, despite all that, you decide to give it a try and manage to get it working, please come back and leave another answer with your solution.

Comment: I tried to get this to work properly since I need it for a project: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYQyJL - take a look at the hover cards at the bottom. I wrapped the svg elements in a div and applied the same classes you had on them to the div and removed them from the svg. The origin and 3d alignment seem to be fixed (the border and size is messed up but it seems fixable by changing the css) on FF 37.0a2 and Chrome 41 (although on Chrome the animation when the cursor leaves has a longer duration for some reason). Is this a solution or did I misunderstand what the problem is?

Comment: @ivy_lynx Yes, that is a practical solution for many of the problems.  My demo was more of an example of everything that makes this question difficult rather than a careful consideration of how to make it work!  The one thing that is missing is to create two "sides" to the card.  You would need nested `<div>`s to get that to work -- one div wrapping each of the sides of the card (one flipped to start), and then an outer div on which you would apply the flipping rotation.  I don't know what's wrong with Chrome -- CSS animations on Codepen have been seriously messed up since I updated to 40.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Are you aware of any compatibility improvements in 2016? I can't find the feature in question on caniuse.com.

Comment: @IsaacLyman The news is still not good, I'm afraid. No support at all in MS Edge for CSS Transforms applied to SVG elements, and things are still buggy with transform-origin & preserve-3D perspective & backface visibility in other browsers. Sorry...

Comment: @AmeliaBR That's okay and thanks for the response. It's too bad about the 3D transforms. But 2D transforms seem to work well enough, and even when they don't, they degrade gracefully, so I can get by with those.

Comment: @IsaacLyman Glad you're okay with adapting. If you're careful, you can avoid transform-origin issues, and use play with opacity to replace backface visibility. Then just make sure the basic layout / `transform` attribute is good for IE / Edge / etc. That's what I did in this demo: https://ameliabr.github.io/great-svg-retcon/images/3D-transforms-with-fallback.svg