# CSS3 Issue about transform animation

Tags: css

I am learning CSS3 features these days. I try to implement an effect of [card flipping](http://jsfiddle.net/rb6L94zL/). (jsfiddle)

Here is the code.

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 5% auto;
    perspective: 500px;
}

#card{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #567890;
    -webkit-animation: flip 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip{
    0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
}

.front, .back{
    position: absolute;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#card .front {
  background: red;
}
#card .back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
```

And HTML.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="card">
        <figure class="front">1</figure>
        <figure class="back">2</figure>
    </div>
/div>
```

Here are the problems.

1. The div has two sides, front and back. The transition should be from front side to back side. But in this program, front side returns.
2. Front side and back side's position are not right. They should be inside the div card.

Can someone help me? Many thanks!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104850/flipping-card-issue/25105063#25105063) is not a like-for-like duplicate but is about  implementing a similar effect and hence adding the link here in comments for your reference. The sample there may help you. For your second issue, just add `margin: 0` to the `.front` and `.back`.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/rb6L94zL/1/) is a version of your fiddle modified based on that answer linked in the previous comment. The logic basically remains the same. The back-side is initially rotated by 180deg and is positioned below the front-side using `z-index` and the effect is reversed on `hover` to give a flip effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of rotating you `.card` why don't you `rotate` the `front` and `back` `div` vice versa

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/rb6L94zL/2/)

added keyframes for `front` and `back` div to rotate

```
@-webkit-keyframes front {
    0% {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes back {
    0% {
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: U r awesome. Now I made a bit change. I use a button to control it and toggle the effect. The link is http://jsfiddle.net/e3k32upg/   But there's something wrong with it. Please help me!!

Comment: this works. but, the effect is a little bit weird. the rotation looks not very naturally.