# CSS Flip card Internet Explorer issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to get a CSS flip card working in Internet Explorer 11. I have read other questions and the solution was to add '-ms' prefixes to the flip card functionality. I have done this but in IE 11, the flipped card does not show the backside for some reason.

http://jsbin.com/hazejuzezu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Any help greatly appreciated.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="flip y-theme-icon-wrapper"> 
    <div class="card text-center"> 
        <div class="face front">
            <div class="y-theme-icon">
                <img src="http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--4bKbxQOb--/1036281511469286726.jpg" height="90" alt="">
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="face back">
            <br><p>More information about this subject.</p>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.y-theme-icon-wrapper{
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}
.y-theme-icon {
    display: block;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    background: @color-1;
    border-radius: 70px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 70px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 70px;
    -o-border-radius: 70px;
    text-align:center;
}
.flip .card .back{
    background-color: #fff;
}
.flip {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    -ms-perspective: 800;
    -moz-perspective: 800;
    -o-perspective: 800;
    position: relative;
    margin: 12px auto;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
  transform:rotatey(-180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Opera */
}
.flip .card {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;  /* W3C */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari & Chrome */
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Firefox */
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Opera */
}
.flip .card .front {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flip .card .back {
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform:rotatey(-180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Opera */
}

/* Postcard */
.postcard-flip {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    -ms-perspective: 800;
    -moz-perspective: 800;
    -o-perspective: 800;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
.postcard-flip .card.flipped {
  transform:rotatey(-180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Opera */
}
.postcard-flip .card {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.postcard-flip .card .face {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;  /* W3C */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari & Chrome */
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Firefox */
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Opera */
}
.postcard-flip .card .front {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.postcard-flip .card .back {
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform:rotatey(-180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Opera */
}
```

**JS Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Card flip */
    $(".flip").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".card").toggleClass("flipped");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: do you see the backside? (white square with 'more information about the subject text)

Comment: Harry - sure, will do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check if [this](http://jsbin.com/gajofawega/2/edit) works for you mate. It works for me in IE11 but kind of provides a very glitchy effect. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104850/flipping-card-issue/25105063#25105063) is a different answer which I wrote earlier and is loosely related to this question. You may find it useful.

Comment: [have a look here](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php) - it' has ie 10 support

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Let me try them and update the question.

Comment: @jbutler483 That doesn't work in ie11 windows10

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using the solution proposed by jbutler483 from a David Walsh blog since it had a smooth flip effect and worked in all browsers. Here my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container y-flip-wrapper" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front text-center">
            <!-- front content -->
            <div class="y-theme-icon">
                <img src="image.png" height="90" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back text-center">
            <!-- back content -->
            <p>More information about this subject.</p>       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    display: inline-block;
}

/*  UPDATED! flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .back {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-container:hover .front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}

.flip-container, .back {
    width: 140px;
}


/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.back{
    margin-top: 24px;
}

/*  UPDATED! front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```