# Images Won't Flip

Tags: html, css

Trying to create similar effect like this: http://callmenick.com/tutorial-demos/image-caption-reveal-on-hover/index-2.html

However i am stuck with my codes and it won't just flip perfectly.

here's my CSS:

```
/* Paragraphs and Heading 2 styling, change according to your needs */
 .slide p, .slide h2 {
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:10px;
    left: -20px;
    top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.slide p {
    font-family:'Lato';
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:18px;
    margin: 0;
}
.slide h2 {
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:24px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family:'Lato';
}
/* 1. Sliding Up */
 .moveup img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -15px;
    width: 100%;
    /*Fit the image to its container. the aspect ratio is preserved; the image will not be distorted*/
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: top .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: top 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
}
.slide:hover img{
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg);
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    /*set to a value to hide the whole image*/
    padding-bottom:200px;
}

.slide:hover .a{
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);

    /*set to a value to hide the whole image*/
    padding-bottom:200px;
}

.a{
    transition:.5s ease-in;
}
```

Any idea which part I made wrong?

Here's the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/r26bz3xn/2/

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: My intention is to help...and they or someone are in bad mood..and don´t give time to adjust my answer...just give negative points. Keep calm

Comment: Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r26bz3xn/5/). I have made some changes to the `transforms` but not adding an answer because the technique is exactly the same as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104850/flipping-card-issue/25105063#25105063) of mine. If you find it difficult to decipher, I would add a full explanation of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use that example, why not just use their structure? I will say that tutorial seemed to have left out quite a lot of styles that made this thing work. I wish I could explain better as to what you were doing wrong but I've added a working fiddle to the bottom and the code below:

**HTML**

```
<figure>
   <img src="http://beautyblenderdupe.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/01.jpg" alt=""/>
   <figcaption>
       <h2>This is a cool title!</h2>
       <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</span>
   </figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
.slide figure {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative; 
}

.slide figure img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}

.slide figure figcaption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5; 
    padding: 20px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide figure h2 {
    font-family:'Lato';
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

.slide figure span {
    display: block;
    font-family:'Lato';
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:18px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #FFF;
}


.slide figure figcaption {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(26, 76, 110, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.slide figure figcaption h3 {
    margin-top: 150px
}
.slide figure img {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.slide figure:hover img,
#effect-2 figure.hover img {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.slide figure:hover figcaption,
#effect-2 figure.hover figcaption {
    transform: rotateY(0);
}`enter code here`
```

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r26bz3xn/6/)

Comment: There were a few problems in the original code mate. (1) The rotation angles 90 & 360 were wrong (2) the backface wasn't hidden initially (by rotating it by 180 or -180 deg)

Comment: Yeah there were more then a few problems, structurally it was wrong, yes the degrees were wrong, and several other things.